# Bootstrap CSS not working on ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have used bootstrap alerts class but it's view is - 
[image]

Instead of -

[image]

I have added the refrence under head tag -

```html
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But still it is not working. Please help as I am new for the webpage.

Comment: You need to reference CSS, not just JS.

Comment: Adding to what SLaks said, reference the CSS with a link tag in your header, and reference the javascript with a script tag at the bottom of your body. You will also need to reference jQuery before the Bootstrap script reference.

Comment: Thanks... I added the bootstrap css refrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the bootstrap CSS to your stylesheet references.

With a CDN:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Alternatively referencing the source from your own server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="*PATH_TO_YOUR_STYLE_FOLDER*/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: I'm sure you could put a _little_ more effort into your answer.  Seeing is you posted this as an _answer_ not a _comment_

Comment: Thanks... I added the bootstrap css refrence.